# how to set the default value to the drop down list control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list control on my web page. I have bind the datatable to the dropdownlist control as follows -

```
lstDepartment.DataTextField = "DepartmentName";
    lstDepartment.DataValueField = "DepartmentID";
    lstDepartment.DataSource = dtDept;
    lstDepartment.DataBind();
```

in the page load event i want to set the default value to the drop down list control from my other table field.

how to do this?

Answer (score 30):

After your `DataBind()`:

```
lstDepartment.SelectedIndex = 0;  //first item

or

lstDepartment.SelectedValue = "Yourvalue"

or 
//add error checking, just an example, FindByValue may return null
lstDepartment.Items.FindByValue("Yourvalue").Selected = true;

or
//add error checking, just an example, FindByText may return null
lstDepartment.Items.FindByText("Yourvalue").Selected = true;
```

Comment: its working exactly what i want. If value not present then i want to set to blank record. how to do this?

Comment: lstDepartment.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));

Comment: i have bind the datatable to the dropdownlist . i used your code for setting default value to blank. but then also it is showing 0th record from the table.

Comment: In my case it also not working. I have id and name and for selectedindex =-1 it's not working and for selectedvalue it's giving error that myvalue is not present. what to do.

Answer (score 5):

if you know the index of the item of default value,just

```
lstDepartment.SelectedIndex = 1;//the second item
```

or if you know the value you want to set, just

```
lstDepartment.SelectedValue = "the value you want to set";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the DropDownList control in the other table also contains DepartmentName and DepartmentID:

```
lstDepartment.ClearSelection();

foreach (var item in lstDepartment.Items) 
{
  if (item.Value == otherDropDownList.SelectedValue)
  {
    item.Selected = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lstDepartment.DataTextField = "DepartmentName";
lstDepartment.DataValueField = "DepartmentID";
lstDepartment.DataSource = dtDept;
lstDepartment.DataBind();
'Set the initial value:
lstDepartment.SelectedValue = depID;
lstDepartment.Attributes.Remove("InitialValue");
lstDepartment.Attributes.Add("InitialValue", depID);
```

And in your cancel method:

```
lstDepartment.SelectedValue = lstDepartment.Attributes("InitialValue");
```

And in your update method:

```
lstDepartment.Attributes("InitialValue") = lstDepartment.SelectedValue;
```