# dropdownlist c# asp default value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tons of posts on this topic, but I can't figure out my issue; hoping you can help -

aspx:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="districtDataSource" runat="server"
SelectMethod="GetAllDistricts"
OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}"                              
TypeName="blah.OrganizationService"                                                      
DataObjectTypeName="blah.baseOrganizationDTO"                                                      
onObjectCreating="districtDataSource_ObjectCreating"
OnSelecting="districtDataSource_Selecting"
OnUpdating="districtDataSource_Updating">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="districtDropDown" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true"
DataSourceID="districtDataSource" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="districtDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I have a c# variable on the code behind that is my user's org id.
I want this drop down when the page loads to default to that orgid

I've tried SelectedValue in the markup, but it fails with the value can't be a declarible.

On my page load, I've tried:

```
districtDropDown.SelectedValue = orgId;
```

The problem is on the page load section, "districtDropDown" is not found. 
I know I need to reference it someway I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Move the SelectedValue code to the districtDropDown_DataBound function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set the default value to the drop down list control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966570/how-to-set-the-default-value-to-the-drop-down-list-control)

Comment: can you post the code behind it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 districtDropDown.DataValueField = "Kid";
 districtDropDown.DataTextField = "Val";
 districtDropDown.DataSource = dt; // your binding the dropdownlist from DataTable..
 districtDropDown.DataBind();
```

**Note:-**

FindByValue may be return null because your OrgId data not Containing in DropDownList Id

```
districtDropDown.Items.FindByValue(orgId).Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in code behind

```
string value = "SomeValue";
var item = districtDropDown.Items.FindByValue(value);
if (item != null)
item.Selected = true;
```